# Glassfish use URL rewriting even though I have not turned off cookies

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

What are the reason that Glassfish resorts to URL rewriting when I am using the latest Chrome browser and logging in to the application without having turned off cookies? Anything I have forgotten to configure or what? It happens randomly.

Comment: Does it use URL rewrite on every request, or just the first request in a new browser session?

Comment: Just the first request, like you are logging in then you are redirected back to the same view as before. But moving around in the application does not cause the session id to be appended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSESSIONID is the value that determines the current HTTP session for the user.  It is typically stored in a browser cookie (named JSESSIONID) to connect requests with the appropriate session object on the server.

The reason why the JSESSIONID is not present in the original request is probably because the server has not had the opportunity to send it back to the browser.  Any links on a page (using c:url, for example) without a current JSESSIONID cookie will be generated using URL rewriting (the URL will contain the jsessionid).  On subsequnt requests, after the JSESSIONID has been stored as a browser cookie, the URL rewrite does not happen.

If the user's browser does not support cookies (or the use of cookies has been turned off) the URL rewriting will allow the user to keep connecting to the same session by the jsessionid added to each URL.

However, if you want to turn off the URL rewriting, you can do this by setting the enableURLRewriting property to false, in the glassfish-web.xml file

```
<property name="enableURLRewriting" value="false"/>
```

You may also have luck removing the URL rewrite by ensuring that the appropriate cookie exists and redirecting to a more appropriate URL.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the first paragraph you wrote? And does it mean that it is "normal" that it is like that the first time?

Comment: It is normal if you have not caused the JSESSIONID cookie to have been created.  If you have have set session="false" in the page tag on your main page, for example.

Comment: Could you try to explain the first paragraph a little better and I accept answer.

Comment: Changed the first paragraph in my answer.